# does range() in generator comprehension takes memory in python 2.7.x

Tags: python-2.7, generator

i'm new to python and I was going through a piece of code and there was range() function in a generator comprehension. does this range() takes memory as usual. because a generator doesn't takes memory instead it creates value on the fly

```
"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))
```

Comment: Just use `xrange` instead of `range`, or switch to Python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, calling `range(100)` immediately allocates a list of size 100 using up memory as usual. Since it is used inside a generator, the values of `str(n)` are created on the fly, but that does not affect the fact that [`range` creates a list, not a generator object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range).

You could implement a simplified version of xrange as follows:

```
# Generates 0, 1, ... n-1
def simple_xrange(n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        yield i
        i+=1
    return
```

(The actual xrange implementation is quite a bit more complicated, since it handles different start values and step sizes, plus optimizations for fast lookup.)

Sample usage: `"-".join(str(n) for n in simple_xrange(10))` results in `'0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9'`

Comment: then what good it does because range() is taking its place in memory.is there any alternative to this excluding xrange()

Comment: The alternative is xrange (or you could write your own function that is equivalent to xrange). Why do you not want to use xrange?

Comment: asked just out of curiosity.

Comment: it helped. thank you. do u mind guiding a litle for writing xrange() type generator. i googled but nothing showed up

Comment: Sure, added to the answer